# How does one pass Outlook Anywhere settings from the Exchange server to Outlook clients?

Tags: outlook, exchange-2010, outlook-anywhere, autodiscovery

Exchange 2010 server.  Outlook 2007 clients.

I have Outlook Anywhere enabled on the server.

If I have a laptop connected to an outside internet connection not on our corporate LAN and manually configure Outlook Anywhere, it works and I am able to connect to our Exchange server.

As soon as the laptop is brought into our network / domain, the incorrect Outlook Anywhere settings are pushed from the server to the client and Outlook Anywhere breaks.

Here are what the working settings look like:
[image]

Here are what the wrong settings that get pushed from the Exchange server look like:
[image]

SERVERNAME being the hostname of our Exchange 2010 server.

Any points in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook Anywhere can be tricky. One of the better resources for this is a site Microsoft runs that checks it from the outside.

https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

Use credentials you don't mind getting out. Or a test account.

Outlook Anywhere also has different contexts for 'inside' and 'outside' as you're learning.

Set-ClientAccessServer -Identity CAServer -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalURI https://mail.company.com/

That sets what internal clients see.

Comment: As expected, it passes the Outlook Anywhere tests if I manually specify the server info but fails using Autodiscover.  Looks like that's my next research topic.  After I look a bit more into I will see if I should edit this question or post another regarding my Autodiscover problems.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make Outlook anywhere use the same domain name internally and externally. On the internal domain I created an additional DNS A record that pointed to the LAN IP of the server running Exchange.

Probably not the best solution but it's worked well so far.